# Rhino mock mocking with complex object as parameter in a method

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have this scenario

```cs
public class ParamObject
{
    public int Prop1 {get; set}
    public int Prop2 {get; set}
    public int Prop3 {get; set}
    public int Prop4 {get; set}
}

public class Respository: IRepository
{
    public string GetSomething(ParamObject myParameter)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}}!", myParameter.Prop1, myParameter.Prop2, myParameter.Prop3, myParameter.Prop4) ;
    }
}


public class MyController
{
    public void MyMethodInMyController(IRepository myRepo)
    {
        ParamObject paramObject = new ParamObject();
        paramObject.Prop1 = 1;
        paramObject.Prop2 = 2;
        paramObject.Prop3 = 3;
        paramObject.Prop4 = 4;

        Console.WriteLine(myRepo.GetSomething(paramObject));
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void Testing()
{
    mocker = new MockRepository();
    mockRepository = mocker.DynamicMock<IRepository>();
    mockRepository
            .Expect(m => m.GetSomething(Arg<ParamObject>.Matches(p => p.Prop1 == 1 && p.Prop2 == 2 && p.Prop3 == 3 && p.Prop4 == 4)))
            .Return("Bye!");
    mocker.ReplyAll();
    MyController myController = new MyController();
    Assert.AreEqual(myController.MyMethodInMyController(mockRepository), "Bye!");
}
```

As you can see, I want to test *MyMethodInMyController* but it requires a call to a method with a complex object as parameter

My test doesn't work and doesn't return an exception, just it stops when calling the method in the call from *MyMethodInMyController*

How can I mock this kind of methods which requires a complez object as parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Note I can't do the mock as

```cs
 mockRepository
             .Expect(new ParamObect(value1, value2, ....)
             .Return("Bye!");
```

because the parameters are different objects and don't match.

Comment: It looks fine to me so far. Just a few recommendations: use AAA syntax (no instance of MockRepository, no ReplayAll and stuff). Use Stub instead of Expect. Don't call your mock mockRepository, this is very confusing! (Why not repositoryMock?)

Comment: The last line of your test doesn't work. MyMethodInMyController doesn't have a return value. On which line does it "stop"? And what does "stop" mean?

Comment: It crash in line Console.WriteLine(myRepo.GetSomething(paramObject)); And stop means the program doesn't continue after this point

Comment: I appreciate a lot your comment. I'm going to change it now

Comment: @Patraix You mentioned " I want to test MyMethodInMyController" BUT not clear what you really trying to test. What exact behaviour you trying to test in your Unit Test? The test method name "Testing" is nothing.

Comment: @Spock this is not my real test, it's just a model for posting. Really I just to ask about mocking a method with a complex object as parameter because now I'm doing it wiht _Arg<ParamObject>.Matches(..._ and the method is crashing in the _Console.WriteLine_ line. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I think, a crash in Console.WriteLine doesn't have anything to do with mocking the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to verify your GetSomething(paramObject) is called with the given parameters, you can write a test like below.

Note that your test code won't even compile MyMethodInMyController won't return a value!

```cs
 Assert.AreEqual(myController.MyMethodInMyController(mockRepository), "Bye!");
```

You can verify the method *GetSomething* method call like below.

```cs
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyMethodInMyController_VerifyGetSomethingIsCalledWithExpectedParamaters()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository>();
        mockRepository
                .Expect(m => m.GetSomething(Arg<ParamObject>.Matches(p => p.Prop1 == 1 && p.Prop2 == 2 && p.Prop3 == 3 && p.Prop4 == 4)))
                .Return("Bye!");
        var sut = new MyController();

        //Act
        sut.MyMethodInMyController(mockRepository);

        //Assert
        mockRepository.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
```

And this should not crash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's like my code, but I think my problem should be another one because it's still crashing without exception message. At least I'm happy knowing the way for working with complex objects in parameters is the proper